# Copy() function PHP, set charset?

Tags: php, character-encoding, gettext

I'm using the gettext in PHP, and because of caching of .mo files, I've a little script, that copies, the original .mo file, and append the time to it, so it gets reloaded. The problem is, using the `copy()` function, seems to ruin the charset of the file?

Because I have a danish translation, danish chars is supported in UTF-8 - the original file is running UTF-8, but after it got copied, it doesn't seem to work for some reason.

```
 <?php
//Starting a session, to store the choosen langauge
session_start();

if (isset($_GET['lang']))
{
    //If the $_GET langauge is set, set the $locale to the get request.
    $locale = $_GET["lang"];
}
else if (isset($_SESSION["lang"]))
{
    //else if the session['lang'] is set, then set the $locale to that session
    $locale = $_SESSION["lang"];
}
else
{
    //Else default is english
    $locale = "en_US";
}

$_SESSION["lang"] = $locale;

$locales_root = "Locale";  // locales directory
$domain = "messages"; // the domain you're using, this is the .PO/.MO file name without the extension

// activate the locale setting
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
setlocale(LC_TIME, $locale);
putenv("LANG=$locale");
// path to the .MO file that we should monitor
$filename = "$locales_root/$locale/LC_MESSAGES/$domain.mo";
$mtime = date('d.H.i.s', strtotime(filemtime($filename))); // check its modification time
// our new unique .MO file
$filename_new = "$locales_root/$locale/LC_MESSAGES/{$domain}_{$mtime}.mo"; 

if (!file_exists($filename_new)) {  // check if we have created it before
      // if not, create it now, by copying the original
      copy($filename,$filename_new);
}
// compute the new domain name
$domain_new = "{$domain}_{$mtime}";
// bind it
bindtextdomain($domain_new,$locales_root);
// then activate it
textdomain($domain_new);
// all done
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, but have you tried setting any of the following first?

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
mb_http_input('UTF-8');
mb_language('uni');
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
ob_start('mb_output_handler');
```

**Edit**

You may also be able to use the 3rd parameter in `copy()` - see docs http://uk.php.net/copy - where it can use `stream_context_create()` to set the header as being UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

I don't think copy() should do anything magical, it should just do a binary copy. Unless maybe theres some setting that operates deep within php's stream functions...

--compare file contents to check

```
printf("%s\n%s", md5_file($filename), md5_file($filename_new));
```